# Windows - Write to the video display directly using kernel driver?

Tags: c, video, windows-7, driver, display

I am in the process of writing a windows 7 kernel driver. Today, I want to have it output debug information via the display. Now I know that I can just use the DbgPrint or the KdPrint functions, but I want to output my string or anything, directly to my monitor. This way, I don't have to fire up Debug View to see my output. This also serves as an educational exercise.

As I understand it, I will have to access the frame buffer for the display and write my values to it, correct? However, I have no clue how to do this. Basically, I want to be able to write something onto the monitor directly, thus it would overlap anything that windows is displaying. I know this might sound weird, but its just for fun.

The main goal is to do this from a KERNEL DRIVER. Not inside a userland process. Note that I am only wanting to use a 640x480 resolution. Not anything higher. If I understand correctly, anything higher than this would require me to write my own display driver for my current video card.

My system setup:
Windows 7 SP1 x86
Intel Pentium 4 @ 3.00Ghz
Nvidia GeForce FX 5200

Thanks for all of you help in advance!

Answer (score 4):

> Now I know that I can just use the DbgPrint or the KdPrint functions, but I want to output my string or anything, directly to my monitor.

You'll have to go through the display driver. Who says that your computer running windows has a monitor at all?

Even if it has, there won't be a MSDOS-style single framebuffer in RAM that stores your current picture. Modern GPUs just don't work that way any more – instead, operating systems ask them to compose the whole screen of single buffers they hand over for compositing – in simplification: Every window is its own framebuffer, and it's the GPU's job to compose everything to a whole screen picture.

You also can't just write to some memory region from your kernel driver just because you like to do so – a) you don't know where that would be and b) you'd compete with other components, and that would be a bad thing.

**EDIT** I feel like I should add this for posteriority:

> the point is very simple: write a driver that is a driver and not a user interface. That's not the job of a driver. Putting UI functionality into a driver is a bad idea for many reasons, and you simply shouldn't do it.

Comment: Ok. How would I go through the display driver in kernel mode?

Comment: Use normal windows API from userland, if possible. That's the way you'd normally handle this: have a daemon in userland running, blocked reading from something that in fact attaches to your kernel driver, and as soon as you have something to display, let that reader know.

Comment: Normally I would use the Windows API. In fact, I would either use Direct2D, or GDI to do this. However, for simplicity and educational sake, I am going to do my display operations in Kernel mode. This way I don't have to have a separate project for the userland app, and the code associated with it. It will be just one simply driver that can visually report things to me.

Comment: So is there some Kernel functions that would allow me to write to the display? Much like the GDI functions in the Win32 API?

Comment: Well, the point is very simple: write a driver that is a driver and not a user interface. That's not the job of a driver. Putting UI functionality into a driver is a bad idea for many reasons, and you simply shouldn't do it.

Comment: I believe the interface for writing a display driver is documented, so *in principle* it might be possible to backwards engineer that to send the display driver IRPs or whatever from kernel mode.  It's unlikely that anybody here already knows how to do it, and it would probably be too complex to post as an answer.  My best guess is that it would take you at least three months to get it working, and that's assuming you're a fricking genius and don't mind too much if it makes the system unstable.  Bottom line, I agree with Marcus: don't bother.